# PyQt4: printing Code 128 barcode fonts

Tags: python, qt, printing, pyqt, code128

I'm trying to write a text in code128 and a printer also ends in a picture, but it does not work in either of the two ways, I looked at the official documentation and other forum questions but it does not print in code128

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication,QImage,QFont
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSizeF
import sys,time
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
image = QImage(640,100,QImage.Format_Mono)
image.fill(1)
font = QFont('code128',32,QFont.Normal)
painter = QPainter()
painter.begin(image)
painter.setFont(font)
text = "\xccasdfsf\xce"
painter.drawText(10,90,text)
painter.end()
image.save('test.png')
```

and also in my thermal printer

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication,QImage,QFont,QPrinter
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSizeF
import sys,time
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
printer = QPrinter('POS-58(copy of 1)')
font = QFont('code128',32,QFont.Normal)
painter = QPainter()
painter.begin(printer)
painter.setFont(font)
text = "\xccasdfsf\xce"
painter.drawText(10,90,text)
painter.end()
```

Neither of these two works for me and I find a solution for this, what could be happening?

The actual output is this[image]

I am using PyQt4 in windows 10 with python 2.7

Comment: What is the meaning of "does not work" and "does not print in code128"? Please describe what is actually printed and/or provide a screenshot showing the output. You should also state what platform you are testing on.

Comment: PS: I tested the first example on my linux system using python-3.6.3, qt-4.8.7, and pyqt-4.12.1, and it works fine for me. That is, it produces an image of a white rectangle with a barcode in the bottom left corner.

Comment: What is the output of `QtGui.QFontInto(font).family()`?. It looks like Qt isn't finding the correct font. Are you sure you installed it properly?

Comment: ```font = QFont('code128')
info = QFontInfo(font)
print(info.family())``` the output is **MS Shell Dlg 2**

Comment: So the font is not installed properly. I have added an answer which should allow you to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it is clear that the **Code 128** font has not been installed properly on your system, so it is falling back to **MS Shell Dlg 2** as a default.

To see exactly which fonts are available to Qt on your system, you can do this:

```
>>> fd = QtGui.QFontDatabase()         
>>> len(fd.families())
209
>>> for f in sorted(fd.families()): print(f)
... 
Adobe Courier
Adobe Helvetica
Adobe New Century Schoolbook
Adobe Times
Adobe Utopia
Arabic Newspaper
B&H Lucida
B&H LucidaBright
B&H LucidaTypewriter
Bitstream Charter
Bitstream Terminal
Bitstream Vera Sans
Bitstream Vera Sans Mono
Bitstream Vera Serif
C059
Cantarell
Code 128
Code 128 low
Code 2 of 5 interleaved
Code 3 de 9
Code Datamatrix
Code EAN13
Code PDF417
D050000L
...
```

If the **Code 128** font doesn't appear in this list, it has definitely not been installed properly. There are plenty of free versions of this font available online (e.g. [Free Barcode Font](http://www.barcodelink.net/barcode-font.php)), so I suggest you try installing some of those instead.

If these fonts *still* don't show up in Qt's list of font families, you can try adding them explicitly, like this:

```
>>> QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('C:\\MyFonts\\code128.ttf')
```

To check that the newly installed font is valid, use [QFontInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontinfo.html):

```
>>> font = QtGui.QFont('Code 128')
>>> info = QtGui.QFontInfo(font)
>>> info.family()
'Code 128'
```

(NB: checking `font.family()` is not sufficient here, because that will only return what was *requested*, rather than what was actually found).

Comment: Glad you got this working - what was the exact problem in the end? (PS: did you know you have the upvoting privilege? Please feel free to test it out on my answer :)